# Understanding what cd_link_conf.xml does

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, dynamic-linking

The docs say:

> The cd_link_conf.xml is the Dynamic Link Resolver configuration file
>   where you can configure optional Publication-specific settings that
>   are used to resolve links.

If I add a node like:

```
    <Publication Id="36">               
        <Host Domain="www.neil.com" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/"/>
    </Publication>
```

My understanding is that any dynamic link resolution using publication Id of "36" will be affected by these settings.

So, in the LINK_INFO table of broker I can see lots of relative urls in the URL column against publication Id **36**, e.g. */private-charter/index.html*.

What I'm expecting is that when I resolve a link, the Link.Url property will be *www.neiltest.com/private-charter/index.html* - a combination of the stored Url and the cd_link_conf settings.

As you've probably guessed by the fact I'm asking this question on TSE, I'm not seeing what I think is the expected behaviour.

Can anyone clarify the effects of using cd_link_conf.xml for me?

**UPDATE**

Came across [another post](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/is-it-possible-to-read-configuration-values-from-within-cd-link-conf-xml-using-t) from Will which mentions that it is possible to to see the behaviour I'm expecting. Perhaps there is an error somewhere ...

Answer (score 3):

My bad - this works exactly as I expected .... once Tridion CD API is set up correctly.